# How to build custom directory structure in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

We need to create our own OS using `freebsd` source code without any additional directories like `/opt`, `/home` and few. Is there any way to remove directory structure creation from `freebsd` source code.

Comment: FreeBSD doesn't have `/opt`.

Comment: yeah, im just saying it as example. if we dont want unnecessary directories what else we can do

Comment: Check `/etc/src.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to write a post-install script that removes stuff you don't need.

You can also change the build system (Makefiles) to install things into desired locations, this is harder and will require additional work when updating FreeBSD source to newer version.